# Live ios(swift) chat, with existing rails web application

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, tcp, chat

I have an existing rails web application with a postgres DB running on the production server and I recently created an ios counter part. I am trying to implement a live chat message within the ios application (the web counter part does not have live chatting).

I have done some research and found that I need to create something called a TCPServer to have a constant communication between the ios application and my rails application. I used daemon to run a simple ruby script on my production server (beside my web application) to test the TCPServer and I was able to run a simple ruby client to connect to the ruby TCPServer and get some static messages.

I have no idea where to go from here. All examples of live ios chatting seem to be writing and receiving data to servers such as firebase. I do not want to do this because I already have a rails application communicating with a postgres database.

How can I get a live chat running on the ios counter part and have both the ios and the web rails communicating to the same database?

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice [tutorial](https://medium.com/@WoloxEngineering/adding-a-realtime-module-to-your-rails-api-18bb562e6441#.6s04mqabz) and eventually figured out how to do this by running node.js & socket.io & redis alongside the rails application. It has diagrams and sample code so it is extremely easy to understand.

In production, Redis will run in the background if your configuration file sets the value for Daemon to true, and the node server will run in the background if you use Forever (a Node packet).